# Remove a dragged element and reset cursor with jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouse-cursor, droppable

I have a problem using drag and drop with jQuery. Here's a very simple fiddle that shows what I mean (http://jsfiddle.net/Znt44/1/):

```
$('#drop').droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
$('#drag').draggable({
    cursor: 'move'
});
```

As you see, I set the cursor to a crosshair when dragged, which works.

If you drop the green box on the red one, the cursor will not reset. It looks like the cursor is attached to the red box as well, and is not resetted.

If you drop the green box anywhere else, the cursor is resetted perfectly.

What is the proper way to reset the cursor?

Or is something wrong with the remove?

Comment: Adding `$('#drop').css('cursor', 'auto');` to the drop function will reset the cursor, but I assume this is not the proper way of doing it.

Comment: I tried a little with developer tools and found out that the cursor style is attached to the body element indeed! This renders some work arounds setting the cursor on the draggable or droppable useless. There must be some other way to do this...

Comment: The best workaround so far: $('body').css('cursor', 'auto')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I noticed that while dragging it forces `style="cursor:move"` on my parent element.
So I forced to `style="cursor:auto"` at the end of drop method (my parent element was `<body>`):

```
$('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think *cursor* style is attached to body for a matter of "layer".
I solved the same issue in my page using style on the class applied by JQuery to the *currently dragged* object:

```
 .ui-draggable-dragging { cursor:move}
```

In this case (in your JSFiddle test case) you can notice that when your drag is hover the droppable element the cursor is the one of the highest z-position element.

Try to change the order of

```
<div id="drag">drag me!</div>
<div id="drop"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="drop"></div>
<div id="drag">drag me!</div>
```

and you see the difference.
Or you can use the *zIndex* property of the .draggable().

If it is appicable to your real case I think it can be a good alternative solution than reset cursor on *body* element, because it is more *specific*.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `cursor: auto` on your droppable:

```
$('#drop').droppable({
cursor: 'auto',
drop: function (e, ui) {
    ui.draggable.remove();
 }
});
$('#drag').draggable({
    cursor: 'move'
});
```

I have edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JudeDuran/Znt44/4/).

Comment: This seems not to work. If the remove is activated again, the cursor still isn't resetted.

Comment: Thanks but I can't see it working. I looked in the jQuery UI docs and didn't found the cursor property of the droppable widget there. Did this really worked for you? (http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: Sorry, I use Chrome and tried again with FF with the same result: the cursor is stuck with the crosshair when moving over the red box after the drop.

Comment: I too get this issue after dropping that the cursor doesn't change back correctly.  The answer here doesn't seem to have any effect.