# AngularJS: cleanest way to fix jQuery bug without updating the DOM in the controller

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I happened to hit [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460182/remove-a-dragged-element-and-reset-cursor-with-jquery) in my Angular app (which uses [Codef0rmer's dragdrop wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460182/remove-a-dragged-element-and-reset-cursor-with-jquery) around jQuery UI's draggable.

It's SO tempting to put the prevailing best solution from that SO answer

```
$('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
```

at the end of my controller function that handles the `stop` event.

It's quick, simple, works like a charm and is unlikely to cause issues because it doesn't update models or bits of the DOM linked to the models.

On the other hand, I fear the Angular police will come after me.

So what's the "Angular" way to do this?

If Codef0rmer's wrapper was my own, I'd just hack in the fix there. But I don't want to mess with that plugin. So my default answer would be

- In the `stop` event function in the controller, set a `dragStopped` flag instead
- Create a whole directive that listens to `dragStopped` to change the CSS property, and
- Add that directive to every draggable element

But this seems ridiculous overkill

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-style.  In the body tag, put

```
ng-style="{cursor: cursorCSS}"
```

In the controller

```
$scope.cursorCSS = 'auto';
```